# Is there a way to split text of an xml at <anchor in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I have the following problem: I have an xml file containing text and I want to collect it into a list (every post being one sublist). But the problem is that the posts sometimes contain more than one sentence - but I need a sublist per sentence.
There is an <anchor type="sentence_start" /> which indicates a new sentence. Is it possible to collect all words between to such anchors (that is sentence per sentence) in a sublist?

Here is a dummy xml with the structure of my real xml:

```
<text>
      <body>
        <div type="logfile">
          <post auto="false" rend="color:blue" synch="#SOME NUMBER" type="standard" who="SOME NUMBER" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">
            <time> 23:20 </time>
            <anchor type="sentence_start"/>
            <w type="NE" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 1</w>
            <w lemma="Lemma 2" type="NN" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 2</w>
            <w lemma="Lemma 3" type="VAFIN" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 3</w>
            <w lemma="Lemma 4" type="ADV" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 4</w>
            <w lemma="." type="$." xml:id="SOME NUMBER">.</w>
            <anchor type="sentence_start"/>
            <w lemma="Lemma 1" type="PWS" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 1</w>
            <w lemma="Lemma 2" type="VAFIN" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 2</w>
            <w lemma="Lemma 3" type="PPOSAT" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 3</w>
            <w lemma="Lemma 4" type="NN" xml:id="SOME NUMBER">Word 4</w>
            <w lemma="?" type="$." xml:id="SOME NUMBER">?</w>
          </post>
        </div>
      </body>
</text>
```

As you can see, I have two anchors, indicating two sentences.

What I've done so far to collect the words in each post:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
single_texts = []

for post in root.iter('POST-TAG'):
    tokens = []

for lemma in post.iter('WORD-TAG'):
    tokens.append(lemma.text)

    single_texts.append([" ".join(tokens)])
    post.clear()
```

What I got (with the example from above):

```
single_texts = [["Word 1", "Word 2", "Word 3", "Word 4", ".", "Word 1", "Word 2", "Word 3", "Word 4", "?"]]
```

What I want is:

```
single_texts = [["Word 1", "Word 2", "Word 3", "Word 4", "."], ["Word 1", "Word 2", "Word 3", "Word 4", "?"]]
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you though about using something like beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did have it roughly. I changed you code slightly:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('post-demo.xml') as handle:
    tree = ET.parse(handle)
    root = tree.getroot()
    single_texts = []

    row = []
    for post in root.iter('post'):
        for element in post:
            if element.tag == 'w':
                row.append(element.text)
            elif element.tag == 'anchor':
                if len(row) > 0:
                    single_texts.append(row)
                    row = []
        if len(row) > 0:
            single_texts.append(row)

print(single_texts)
```

The result is as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, with `beautifulsoup`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


xml_doc = '''... the xml string from the question'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, 'html.parser')

out = {}
for w in soup.select('w'):
    out.setdefault(id(w.find_previous('anchor')), []).append(w.text)

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```
[
  ['Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3', 'Word 4', '.'], 
  ['Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3', 'Word 4', '?']
]
```